# Laravel does not open the required page in the category

Tags: php, laravel, routes

If you try to open the category (tables) and select (Red table with white borders) in it, then such a page will open without problems and information will be on this table, but if you open in the same category (tables), another table, for example (Blue table with white inserts), then again the red table will open, but the path to the blue table will open in the browser address bar. This is the information when I go to the red table Using the dump command I get the following result:

```php
"id" => 1
    "title" => "Red table with white borders"
    "alias" => "red-table-with-white-borders"
    "img_path" => "none"
    "description" => "fuf"
    "created_at" => "2024-01-20 16:23:11"
  ]
    "categories" => 
            "id" => 1
            "title" => "Table Gaming"
            "alias" => "table-gaming"
            "pivot_service_id" => 1
            "pivot_category_id" => 1
```

And exactly the same information when I go to the blue table I am attaching the source data in the controller in the view and in the paths

**ItemController.php**

```php
/**
   * @param $catname
   * @return Application|Factory|View|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application
   */
  public function getCategoriesItem($catname)
  {
    $data = Category::where('alias', $catname)->with('services')->firstOrFail();
    if (!$data){
      abort(404, 'Page not found');
    }
    return view('template.sait.page.categories.show', compact('data'))->with('alias', $catname);
  }
  public function getServicesFormCategory($alias)
  {
    $items = Service::whereHas('categories', function ($categories) 
    use($alias)
    {
      $categories->where('alias', $alias);
    })
      ->with('categories')
      ->with('doctors')
      ->first();
    if (!$items){
      abort(404, 'Page Not found');
    }
    dd($items);
    // return view('template.sait.page.categories.show.view', compact('items'))->with('alias', $alias);
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('categories/{catname}', [ItemController::class, 'getCategoriesItem'])->name('www.categories.show');
Route::get('categories/{catname}/{alias}', [ItemController::class, 'getServicesFormCategory'])->name('www.categories.services.show');
```

**view (Blade)**

```php
<div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-3 justify-between">
      @foreach($data->services as $link)
        <a 
        class="tw-btn-info" 
        href="{{route('sait.categories.get.services', ['catname' => $data->alias, 'alias' => $link->alias])}}">
        {{$link->title}}</a>
      @endforeach
    </div>
```